# Discriminant of a ternary quadratic form

Tags: determinant, quadratic-forms

What is the discriminant of a ternary quadratic form $x^2-y^2+z^2-2xy+4yz-6xz$?

The answer says, first make it $a_{11}x^2+a_{22}y^2+a_{33}z^2+2a_{12}xy+2a_{23}yz+2a_{13}xz$, and then the discriminant equals $\operatorname{det} (A)$, where $A$ is the $3\times3$ matrix with entries $a_{11},\cdots ,a_{33}$

So the answer based on this definition, equals to $15$.

Since there is little discussion about this concept online, I find

http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~kap/Forms/shorter.pdf

where, based on his method, it gets to $60$. Which one is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is that  $$ 4 \cdot 15 = 60.   $$
When Kap and I and Alexander wrote the original paper, 1997, see http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/bib.html , we separated forms with all the "off-diagonal" or $yz,zx,xy$ coefficients even. You have been given such a form. Conway has proposed calling these "integral matrix" because we get
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -1 & -3 \\
-1 & -1 & 2 \\
-3 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which has determinant $15.$

Eventually I found that it was easier to write the many related computer programs by treating the discriminant in a uniform manner. Now i write all discriminants as in, for a well-known instance, Lehman 1992, see http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/forms.html
which is just four times the determinant.

Since you evidently have a book with an answer key, i suggest you follow that.

Lehman's discriminant is this: given
$$ f(x,y,z) = a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2 + r yz+ s zx+ t xy,   $$
the discriminant is
$$ \Delta = 4abc + rst - ar^2 - b s^2 - ct^2.  $$
Note that this is an integer, even when $r,s,t$ are allowed to be odd numbers at times.

By the way, most authors who do quadratic forms full time would say the discriminant is $120.$ Nothing I can do about that.

Comment: its not a book. instead, it is a solution full of errors..so i want to be more cautious. thanks for your answer!

Comment: by the way, Conway? do you mean the British mathematician John Conway?

Comment: Yes, John Horton Conway, at Princeton for many years. The other famous one is John Bligh Conway, books on complex analysis, i think he is American.

Comment: Both of them have fancy names, and so do I.

Comment: Alright. Anyway, usage varies. An author has the responsibility to specify what conventions he is using, but does not really have the responsibility to use exactly the same conventions as someone else. There is considerable historic variation in definitions of discriminant for quadratic forms.